# What is the fastest java framework/server combo?

Tags: java, webserver, web-frameworks

I'm absolutely confused by all the choices out there. Glassfish, jersey, jax-ws, Grizzly, nginx, cherokee...all of them could be used as a web server and/or application server.

Then there is the framework side. I want that side to be as small as humanly possible. I'm not very happy with the kind of frameworks I found in java, but this one looks good:
http://code.google.com/p/spark-java/

But no mention of performance or anything. Does that mean that the server is mainly responsible for the performance and I can use 'spark' with something like nginx? Which would take care of all my performance problems? Maybe put Varnish in front of it for caching?

What is the simplest, fastest solution in java? I'd like something like tornado, gevent, nodejs...only in java.

Comment: You don't need performance until you do, and any application server will do more than you need. This is the worst possible kind of pre-optimization.

Comment: Not really an answer, but the speed of your framework probably doesn't matter at all. Database access will be 99+% of your time no matter what you do.

Comment: Lies, damned lies, and benchmarks. One of the advantages of Java is that his lots of standards so you can easily swap out your components. So why not worry about fastest this or that till its a problem.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm worrying about it now because I can. It doesn't matter to me what I use, so I'd prefer to not have to rewrite everything when I finally hit the performance wall. I'm not building a tiny blog which can be cached away, my website is dynamic and is supposed to scale to millions of requests per day.

Comment: Question is, what are you're requirements?  Need to support j2ee, then you need an app server that provides all of that baggage..  Need a rich programming environment, web framework with components, etc?  What are you willing to sacrifice to get performance?  If performance is your only requirement, why not use something like lighttpd and forget java

Comment: @jskaggz: Requirements: Java + minimal webframework + performance. I want java because it has convenient access to many databases and has static typing.

Comment: I personally enjoy tapestry on tomcat, and some of the applications we've put out have an incredibly high concurrent user count, achieved by careful hardware selection, much performance testing and optimizing of the *application code* with things like Jmeter and a profiling tool.  To your requirements I say: handcoded servlets + jetty        But...there is no golden hammer or silver bullet :-) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GoldenHammer  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SilverBullet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already mentioned, this seems like a case of "premature optimization", but if you really want to go for performance try the [Simple HTTP Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/). Or a small servlet container like [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). They make you start at a pretty basic level and you can evolve your application from there.

As soon as you hit a database though, the performance overhead from any application server or web framework will become insignificantly small.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Grails Framework](http://www.grails.org), deploy on [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), and when performance becomes an issue scale with [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/).

Comment: Grails uses Groovy which is dynamically typed. I want to use Java. Moreover it is based on Spring. (which is a complexity monster). Absolutely not what I want, as I said the web framework part has to be as minimal as possible.

Comment: So you're saying you want to reinvent the wheel.  Been there done that.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I personally enjoy tapestry on tomcat, and some of the applications we've put out have an incredibly high concurrent user count, achieved by careful hardware selection, much performance testing and optimizing of the application code with things like Jmeter and a profiling tool.  For other applications, j2ee is in play, so we're talking jboss and the like.

To your requirements I say: handcode your servlets and deploy them on jetty.  But remember...there is no golden hammer or silver bullet :-) c2.com/cgi/wiki?GoldenHammer  c2.com/cgi/wiki?SilverBullet

Answer (score 0):

The framework that has the fewest network calls will be the fastest.  In other words, it doesn't matter which framework you will use, as waiting on the network will kill performance in any framework.